# Anchor not always jumping to the same location

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, anchor

I have a [website](https://artistatours.com/) and an [anchor link](https://artistatours.com/#about_us) (#about_us).

**The problem is that is not jumping always to the same position.**

I have a **#page_header** with **position:fixed**.

I searched a bit and tried with this fix:

```
#about_us{

    scroll-margin-top: 10em !important; /*2*/

}
```

but the anchor is still not jumping to the same location, from all pages.

**What could be the problem? And how can I fix it?**

Thanks advanced

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post with enough information for us to help _without going elsewhere_. Also, [never link "link"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking).

Comment: The only time it doesn't seem to work for me is if I've scrolled to another position, then refresh. It's normal browser behavior to retain the last position before refresh, overriding the previous anchor position. If that's not what you're describing, please include a reproduction process in your revisions.